# Javascript to enable/disable textbox on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, web, checkbox

Couldn't be because of browser differences. I have tested in Chrome aswell. Could it be an error in my code? When I press the check box, the textbox is suppose to be disabled. this doesn't have so far. Here is the code I have:
I put the script on the top of the  section of the page.

Form name : frmPost

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function enabledisable() {
                if (document.getElementById("ePrice").checked) {    
                    document.frmPost.txtPrice.disabled=false;
                } else {
                    document.frmPost.txtPrice.disabled=true;
                }
            }​
    </script>

<input type="text" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice" size="5">
<input type="checkbox" id="ePrice" name="ePrice"  onclick="enabledisable()"/>
```

Comment: did you try to use firebug to detect issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked it on IE9, Chrome and Firefox

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function enabledisable() {
                if (document.getElementById("ePrice").checked) {    
                    document.frmPost.txtPrice.disabled=false;
                } else {
                    document.frmPost.txtPrice.disabled=true;
                }
            }
    </script>
<form name="frmPost">
<input type="text" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice" size="5" disabled="disabled">
<input type="checkbox" id="ePrice" name="ePrice"  onclick="enabledisable()"/>
</form>
```

All is ok. Are you sure, that your form is named as frmPost?
And I believe that input txtPrice should be disabled by default

Comment: yes the naming is right, but what's really weird is that when i add `disabled='disabled`, javascript freezes my browser for two to three seconds. what could this be?

Comment: that is all you have on the page?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="txtPrice" id="txtPrice" size="5">
<input type="checkbox" id="ePrice" name="ePrice"/>



$("input[name='ePrice']").click(function() {
    $("input[name='txtPrice']").attr("disabled", this.checked);
 });
```

I have update for you this is latest

http://jsfiddle.net/H8VPY/84/

Comment: no browser works so I have been looking at the rest of my code this time.

Comment: In a way, your new js is too powerful, it disables every textbox on the page. Although it is not working on my project, I must spend some more time to do some tests

Comment: This answer requires the use of the jQuery library (jquery.com) so you would need to include that in your page e.g. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes it need to include the refrence of jquery <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>include in your head tag